# Changing Variables in an if statement

Tags: angularjs, firebase, if-statement, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

My code currently has the following variable :

```
var ref = firebase.database.ref("players").child("week1");
$scope.players = ref;
```

But what I want to do is change the ref based on a particular date.

This is what I have tried:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
var q = d.getDate();

if (n ===4 && q ===3) {
var ref = var ref = firebase.database.ref("players").child("week1");
} if (n === 4 && q === 5){
var ref = firebase.database.ref("players").child("week2");
}
```

But the code does not work. Is there a way to change the database node that is queried based on the date via an if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you declare `ref` variable each time inside the conditions. it makes the variable scope limited to the relevant condition. Declare the variable outside of the condition.

```
var ref 
if (n ===3 && q ===4) {
   ref = firebase.database.ref("players").child("week1");
} 
if (n === 4 && q === 5){
  ref = firebase.database.ref("players").child("week2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deji James, actually today is the third day of the week so the n must be 3 and the date is 4-10-2017, so q must 4.

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
var q = d.getDate();

if (n ===3 && q ===4) {
   var ref = firebase.database.ref("players").child("week1");
} 
if (n === 4 && q === 5){
 var ref = firebase.database.ref("players").child("week2");
}
```

This what i understood from your question, if you want more you can edit your question with what you want fully.